# C++14 encounters strange "use of deleted function" error

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, auto

I've got a simple snippet below for g++7.3.1 -std=c++14

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct S{
    int m_i = 2;
    auto& get2(){return ref(m_i);}
};
int main(){
    S s;
    s.get2()=4;
    cout<<s.m_i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles with error as below:

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::reference_wrapper<int>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::reference_wrapper<int>’
    auto& get2(){return ref(m_i);}
                        ~~~^~~~~
In function ‘int main()’:
error: use of deleted function ‘std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>::reference_wrapper(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = int]’
    s.get2()=4;
            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:44:0,
                from /usr/include/c++/7/functional:58,
                from xxx.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/refwrap.h:338:7: note: declared here
    reference_wrapper(_Tp&&) = delete;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know, by removing the "ref" wrapper, the program gets compiled. I just wish to know what's the problem with using "ref" here?

1. As long as I wish to return a reference, why adding a "ref" here causes error?
2. I don't get the point why g++ saw it as "use of deleted function", which function is being deleted?

Comment: What's actually unclear about the error message?

Comment: `get2` returns a reference. This is a problem because 1) it would be a dangling reference (the instance it refers to goes out of scope at the end of the function) and 2) you can't bind a non-`const` reference to a temporary object like the one obtained from `ref(m_i);`. Just return by value.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Why dangling?

Comment: is there some real problem you are trying to solve? Your example seems to be only for reproducing the error, but otherwise I dont understand why you wrote that

Comment: @Rakete1111 The function returns a reference to a temporary `std::reference_wrapper`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of problems with the code you've shared.

The first problem is that you are returning a reference to an object that will no longer exist when your function returns. `std::ref` returns an `std::reference_wrapper` which will go out of scope. An `std::reference_wrapper` is an object that gives some of the functionalities of a reference type while still behaving like an object. It has move semantics, so the correct usage would be to return the `std::reference_wrapper` by value.

```
#include<functional>
struct S {
    int m_i = 2;
    auto get2() { return std::ref(m_i); }
};
```

Though as others have pointed it out, `std::ref` is not really needed here. You can just return a reference to `m_i` directly. If a user happens to actually need an `std::reference_wrapper` for that `int`, they can call `std::ref` themselves with the reference to `m_i` you provide.

```
struct S {
    int m_i = 2;
    int & get2() { return  m_i; }
};
```

But that's not the only problem with your code. Assuming you fix the first issue and return your `std::reference_wrapper` by value, you are still misusing `std::reference_wrapper::operator=`. That operator does not assign a new value to the referred object. Instead, it rebinds the reference to refer to a different instance. The correct usage would be to use `get()` to get a proper assignable `int&` from the `std::reference_wrapper` :

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>
struct S {
    int m_i = 2;
    auto get2() { return std::ref(m_i); }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.get2().get() = 4;
    std::cout << s.m_i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But what about the error message? The compiler sees that the only [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%3D) that exists for `std::reference_wrapper` is one that takes another `std::reference_wrapper`. So it tries to implicitly convert `4` to an `std::reference_wrapper` the only way it can, by trying to use the constructor that takes a single argument. However, it's not possible to create an `std::reference_wrapper` to a literal like `4` (or rvalues in general). It needs a proper lvalue to refer to. This is prevented by declaring a constructor that accepts rvalue references to the wrapped type (in this case `int`) and deleting it. Attempting to use that constructor will produce the error you are seeing. The deleted function is `std::reference_wrapper<int>::reference_wrapper<int>(int&&)`, which is called by the conversion introduced by the compiler.

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 5):

`std::ref` doesn't merely return a reference, it returns a *Reference Wrapper*. Specifically, `std::reference_wrapper<T>`. So when you write `return std::ref(m_i);`, you're not returning `int&`, you're returning `std::reference_wrapper<int> &`, a reference to a dangling object that itself contains a reference.

Just return the member as-is; the compiler will understand that it's meant to be a reference.

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>
//Don't use using namespace std;, it's bad practice

struct S{
    int m_i = 2;
    auto& get2(){return m_i;}
};
int main(){
    S s;
    s.get2()=4;
    std::cout<<s.m_i<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Consider also instead making the return type explicit, since this isn't a situation where you benefit much from the use of `auto`.

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>

struct S{
    int m_i = 2;
    int& get2(){return m_i;}
};
int main(){
    S s;
    s.get2()=4;
    std::cout<<s.m_i<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```